# PHP Обратиться к ассоц.массиву по переменной специального формата

Tags: php, массивы

Есть некий ассоциативный массив, например, **config**, вложенность любая:

```
$config = [
    'name' => 'Название',
    'db' => [
         'username' => 'root',
         'charset' => 'utf8'
     ]
];
```

И дана переменная string $get, для доступа к элементам массива.
Формат ее: name1<.name2><.nameN>

```
Т.е. если $get = 'name'; то возвращаем => $config['name'];

а если $get = 'db.username'; соответственно => $config['db']['username];
```

Как бы это реализовать?..

Comment: `explode` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php  по точке.... дальше пробегаемся циклом по массиву, собирая значения как ключи `$config` разного уровня

Comment: Спасибо. foreach по explode, далее рекурсивный перебор массива конфига, пока не найдем нужный элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочее решение. 
throw Exception можно заменить на другое действие, но если это действие не будет прерывать работу цикла, обязательно используйте break или return.

```
$config = [
    'name' => 'Название',
    'db' => [
        'username' => 'root',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
    ]
];

$get = 'db.username';
$path = explode('.', $get);

$varable = $config;

foreach ($path as $key) {
    if (!isset($varable[$key])) {
        throw new \Exception('Not found');
    }

    $varable = $varable[$key];
}

print_r($varable); // root
```

Это решение позволяет получать любые значения. Например, если $get = 'db', то $varable будет содержать массив

```
[
  'username' => 'root',
  'charset' => 'utf8'
]
```